# R: Merge information from 2 columns together

Tags: r, dplyr

I have created an example dataframe which has 3 different groups with 2 columns for each group.

Group_1 shows the total amount of participants and Group_1_Pos shows how many of the total participants are positive, etc:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"), 
                       Group_1 = c("100", "200", "300", "400"), 
                       Group_1_Pos = c("10", "20", "30", "40"),
                       Group_2 = c("500", "600", "700", "800"),
                       Group_2_Pos = c("50", "60", "70", "80"), 
                       Group_3 = c("900", "1000", "1100", "1200"),
                       Group_3_Pos = c("90", "100", "110", "120")), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names=c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
> df1
  Date Group_1 Group_1_Pos Group_2 Group_2_Pos Group_3 Group_3_Pos
1 2016     100          10     500          50     900          90
2 2017     200          20     600          60    1000         100
3 2018     300          30     700          70    1100         110
4 2019     400          40     800          80    1200         120
```

I would like to combine the total participant columns together with the positive participant columns in a way that keeps both values still seperated with brackets. As an example:

```
  Date      Group_1    Group_2     Group_3 
1 2016     100 (10)    500 (50)    900 (90)          
2 2017     200 (20)    600 (60)  1000 (100)        
3 2018     300 (30)    700 (70)  1100 (110)       
4 2019     400 (40)    800 (80)  1200 (120)
```

So in this example I add the positive participants in () brackets next to the total participants and only keep 3 columns for the 3 groups.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you could go for something like:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(Group_1 = paste0(Group_1, " (", Group_1_Pos, ")"),
         Group_2 = paste0(Group_2, " (", Group_2_Pos, ")"),
         Group_3 = paste0(Group_3, " (", Group_3_Pos, ")"),) %>% 
  select(-contains("Pos"))

#   Date  Group_1  Group_2    Group_3
# 1 2016 100 (10) 500 (50)   900 (90)
# 2 2017 200 (20) 600 (60) 1000 (100)
# 3 2018 300 (30) 700 (70) 1100 (110)
# 4 2019 400 (40) 800 (80) 1200 (120)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `purrr`-`dplyr`-`stringr`:

```
    other_values <- df1[,seq(1,ncol(df1),2)]
       df1 %>% 
   select(-contains("Pos")) %>% 
   purrr::map2_df(.,other_values, 
                  function(x,y) paste0(x," (",y,")")) %>% 

   mutate(Date=stringr::str_remove_all(Date,"\\s.*"))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Date  Group_1  Group_2  Group_3   
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     
1 2016  100 (10) 500 (50) 900 (90)  
2 2017  200 (20) 600 (60) 1000 (100)
3 2018  300 (30) 700 (70) 1100 (110)
4 2019  400 (40) 800 (80) 1200 (120)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R way of doing what the question asks for.
Get the columns to be pasted with a regex and `grep`, then loop through the indices vector and paste them together. Finally, `cbind` the first column and this result.

```
inx <- grep("\\d$", names(df1))
tmp <- sapply(inx, function(i) paste(df1[[i]], paste0("(", df1[[i + 1]], ")")))
res <- cbind(df1[1], tmp)
names(res)[-1] <- names(df1)[inx]

res
#  Date  Group_1  Group_2    Group_3
#1 2016 100 (10) 500 (50)   900 (90)
#2 2017 200 (20) 600 (60) 1000 (100)
#3 2018 300 (30) 700 (70) 1100 (110)
#4 2019 400 (40) 800 (80) 1200 (120)
```

Final clean up.

```
rm(inx, tmp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given 3 groups, here is a base R solution that can give you the desired output

```
n <- 3
dfout <- cbind(df1[1],
               `colnames<-`(sapply(seq(n), function(k) paste0(df[[x <- paste0("Group_",k)]]," (", df[[paste0(x,"_Pos")]],")")),
                            paste0("Group",seq(n))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  Date   Group1   Group2     Group3
1 2016 100 (10) 500 (50)   900 (90)
2 2017 200 (20) 600 (60) 1000 (100)
3 2018 300 (30) 700 (70) 1100 (110)
4 2019 400 (40) 800 (80) 1200 (120)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more general tidyverse solution

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
      rename_at(
        vars(contains("Pos")),
        ~ str_remove(., "_Pos") %>% str_remove("Group_") %>% str_c("Pos", ., sep = "_")
      ) %>%
      pivot_longer(Group_1:Pos_3,
                   names_to = c(".value", "set"),
                   names_sep = "_") %>%
      mutate(Pos = Pos %>% str_c("(", ., ")")) %>%
      unite("result", Group:Pos, sep = "") %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = set, values_from = result)
```